# Import multiple CSV files into master excel spreadsheet and append the data to previous imports

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a script that imports a .csv file into worksheet "Data"

After the first import all following ones appear to the right of the previous imports and not added onto the bottom (last row).

I think the issue involves this area of the script:
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1"))

```
Sub load_csv()
    Dim fStr As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'fStr is the file path and name of the file you selected.
        fStr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fStr, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "CAPTURE"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at the answers on this site that already address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the destination to see what the next unused cell is.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    .QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
  ..., Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'lots of other stuff
End With
```

You can rereference the ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") repeatedly but using a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) is easier.